# How to update SharePoint online file's metadata using REST API?

Tags: c#, api, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm brand new to interacting with SharePoint online's REST API's and I'm trying to figure out how to update metadata associated with files in a document library. I've added a few columns that I want to populate.

I need to use only the web services and not any SharePoint assemblies because they are not available on the machine I'm using for various reasons.

I'm having trouble understanding the SP documentation and for some reason I can't seem to find a good example of updating metadata without using `CSOM` or the `PnP` assemblies.

Any suggestions with the correct APIs to look at and/or how to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample Rest API request to update a file metadata in default Documents library:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
updateFileMetadata();
function updateFileMetadata() {
        var def = jQuery.Deferred();
        var restSource= "http://sp/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/Items(11)";        
        var itemPayload = {"__metadata": {"type":"SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem"},"Title":"Updated"};
        var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: restSource,
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(itemPayload),
            headers:
                {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
                    "If-Match": "*"

                },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");
                dfd.resolve(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                dfd.reject(err);
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
        return dfd.promise();
    }
</script>
```

[image]